# Proxy for users search

Tags: discussion

It has drawn my attention that when doing a search for a particular user, one has to use the exact name. For example, if I was looking for Lizzie Commodore, but instead remembered the spelling wrong and typed in Lizzy Commodore, then nothing would be returned.

I am sure, there are people like me, who have short memories, or maybe they have fat fingers. Either ways, would it not be nice for the results to return some almost matches if no exact match is found?

Answer (score 6):

Google has pampered you, my friend :). Identifying "almost matches" is a big task. It's not just "pump a few regexes into the system and we're done". English is far from consistent,  and to get this to work for *posts* is a very, very large project. To get it to work for *names* is pretty much impossible (remember, folks have non-English usernames as well. And strange concotions like my username) . Google works on statistical analysis, it "learns" about misspellings from its large database. SE doesn't have a large database.

Searching for users isn't an often-used feature. If you think you misspelled it, try a variation. It takes less than five seconds to search. I can see how this feature is useful for the site search, but again, you can just fix it yourself and re-search.

Do we really need to waste tons of dev time on a project that will save you the trouble of trying a few variations of a search term?

---

Anyway, you can always use Google with `site:stackoverflow.com`, for both normal search and user search (can't use the operators though.)

Comment: Worst-case, you can just use Google with `site:stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: @Xeo: Eexactly.

Comment: Well, they "wasted tons of dev time" on a project that spawned a whole new generation of help vampires so, _yeah_! Why not?

Comment: "English is far from consistent, and to get this to work for posts is a very, very large project." Hmm, are we required to have English names on this site?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: That is neither relevant nor constructive; could you _please_ stop harping on the changes to the close menu (which, IIRC, were tweaked to be acceptable)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: good point :)

Comment: @Manishearth: Huh? When did I mention the close menu?

Comment: I thought @lightness was referring to SO itself :-).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Ohhhhhh. Sorry about my comment then. Somehow I have associated your username with whining about the close changes :P (I thought there was some part that spawned help vampires, wasn't in the mood to find out what). :)

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards got it :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yep, it was just me who didn't :P The other day, someone mentioned that the reason that the world is so full of copy-paste programmers is that resources like SO exist for them. It's a vicious cycle.